How can I view all work item tags of my project in azure devops
I would like to know if there is any visual way through Azure Devops Services where I can view all the Workitem TAGS created in my project.
I managed to find how to search for tags via the Azure Devops REST API, but I would like to know if there is a visual way to see the same tags?
REST API:
https://dev.azure.com/Organization/ProjectLorenIpsum/_apis/wit/tags?api-version=7.1-preview.1
Thank you in advance for all your help
Expect to find some visual menu in Azure devops with this information

Visual Way to view all Tags in a Project

Click on "Boards" and select "Work Items".
Open the "Tags" Filter, Click on the dropdown to see a list of all tags.


You can as well filter Work Items by tags

Click on "Boards", select "Queries" and click on "New Query"



Add Tags you which to filter workitems with as shown in the screenshot below:



Run Query



Thank you very much for the answer it helped me

I am afraid that there are no other ways as of now to list the work item tags of a project in the Azure DevOps WEB UI, than the workaround suggested by @nacho to list the work item tags in the dropdown menu of a query criteria. (The Global filter of Recent updated of Work items hub or a team filter of Backlogs hub etc. may affect the tags to be listed.)
Per the current limistation, you could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.


I would like to know if there is a visual way to see the same tags?

Yes. I suggest that you can use the extension: Tags Manager.
It allows you to manage all your team project work item tags (rename, merge and delete).
For example: Navigate to Boards -> Tags tab


Thank you very much for the answer it helped me

@Thwyster Glad to know that the answer can give you help.
